# angular-cli broken state unable to reinstall: Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined"

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

then clean the cacge and install the new version

```
npm cache clean
npm i --save -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.21
```

Then I run `ng --version` and get the error:

```
Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined".
```

Is there another check I can do to avoid this error?

Comment: why a u installing beta.21?

Comment: i am using a plugin for a datepicker which currently does not work with the latest version of the cli (the fix is planned for a few weeks time, hence I am reverting back - or trying to revert back..)

Comment: I would rather find the new datepicker that supports the latest :) otherwise  check your project `node_modules` `angular` folder `package.json` file and see what exact version number is there.

Comment: In hindsight, that may have been a better option. However, I like this datepicker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker) and I'm told by the developer who's creating it that the fix will be released in about 1 week, so I am prepared to wait

Comment: i'm installing it outside a project to avoid complication with current project state and actually not doing the --save on the install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you running `ng -v` on a `cli` project folder you are getting the local `cli` version.

Run `ng -v` outside your project folder to get a global `cli` version.

Also try to remove `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install` it might fix your local error.

**P.S**

I c you are straggling with the `datepicker` so you have to rather change to different one or continue to resolve to `npm modules`.

Check this [datepicker](https://github.com/IckleChris/ic-datepicker) and [online demo](https://icklechris.github.io/ic-datepicker/example) may be you will like this one - it is already supported `angular v4` so you can use the latest `cli`. Also if you are interested [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2/) team soon gonna be releasing [datepicker](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/675) component.

Otherwise you have to fight the `npm modules` versions to fix your issue.

Comment: ng -v is a good tip, but still gives the same error. I actually tried deleting the node-modules folder just a few minutes ago and unfortunately it did not work

Comment: thanks, just testing out this new datepicker solution now

Comment: i've been watching the angular material repo - i'm looking forward to using this datepicker. The other datepicker you suggested looks very nice, I think that I will go with this option. I am currently unable to get the options working. I'm passing in an options object which implements the interface, but they do not have any effect.

Comment: it seems that this datepicker does not support version 4 of angular, only version 2.

Comment: see the https://github.com/IckleChris/ic-datepicker/blob/master/package.json it is referencing `@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0`. If you have any issues with that datepicker is it sounds like a different question ;)

Comment: I think it depends on @angular/forms@2.4.0 . forms 2.4.0 depends on angular 2.4.0 (see peer dependencies). I am using: https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker for now . Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of the Angular-cli is specified as `@angular/cli`.

Use:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

I believe the name was changed to use the `@` symbol when it came out of beta.

Comment: i will upvote because this was helpful. I did not know about this change in version and will try to migrate to it now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to older version of `angular-cli`.
If you run

```
ng -v
```

output will be

```
@angular-cli: 1.0.0 beta...
```

The proper way to remove `angular-cli` globally is

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

run these commands with `sudo`. If this works, then Congrats.

But in my case this didn't work. Because after running above commands, now there are two angular-cli installed. One (older) installed locally at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and other newer one globally at `/usr/lib/node_modules`. Now, I manually removed the angular-cli from local folder.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli
```

Now, if you run

```
ng -v
```

You will find

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
```